# Where can I ask questions related to RDF, LDP, REST etc.?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have posted the question in superuser.com, but not sure if it is the right place. Can this question be redirected to proper community: https://superuser.com/questions/1054355/what-is-the-difference-between-rest-and-ldp

Answer (score 2):

Those frameworks are programming related, and questions on that subject are on-topic on [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com).

However, "What is the difference between X and Y" type of questions tend to become endless lists of differences, with little usefulness for future readers. Personally I would vote to close such a question as "too broad", but that is my opinion.